# Close entire app when back button clicked twice?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using this code:

```
 private static long back_pressed;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) super.onBackPressed();
        else Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "click again to leave", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
      }
```

It only closes the current Activity, how to close the entire app when back button is clicked twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following:

```
@Override
 public void onBackPressed() {

    if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {

     android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        System.exit(1);
    }
    else Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "click again to leave", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try it